# Brownian motion : first time it reach $1$ is in mean infinite. Does it make sense?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Let $(W_t)$ a Brownian motion (starting at $0$) and $\tau=\inf\{t>0\mid W_t\geq 1\}$. Using reflexion principle in $(*)$, I find that $$\mathbb P\{\tau>t\}=\mathbb P\{\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}W_s<1\}\underset{(*)}{=}\mathbb P\{|W_t|<1\}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^1e^{-x^2/2t}dx,$$
and thus $$\mathbb E[\tau]=\int_0^\infty \mathbb P\{\tau>t\}dt=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 e^{-x^2/2t}dxdt=\infty .$$

I find this result quit non-intuitive, since I would interpret it as : in mean, the BM is smaller than 1, which is - I guess - wrong. So, I was wondering : is my calculation wrong ?

Comment: Maybe it's the notation that's confusing me - but if I take $t$ to be very close to $0$ in your first line, I'm calculating the probability that $\tau$ is greater than some real very close to $0$, yes? Which should be $1$. But it tends to $0$. Conversely for large $t$.

Comment: I mean, surely (*) is just wrong.

Comment: @Frank: Why ? This is just [reflexion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process))

Comment: I don't know enough to comment on the details here, but in a simple (50/50 left/right) one dimensional random walk, the expected time to reach $1$ starting from $0$ is infinite (even though $1/2$ the time you get there in one step). Maybe this is sort of a continuous variation of that?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(\tau)=\infty$ is correct but your interpretation is not. It is possible to show that $\mathbb{P}(\tau<\infty)=1$, i.e the sample paths of Brownian motion will be eventually greater or equal than $1$ at some point. The identity $\mathbb{E}(\tau)=\infty$ tells us that we may have to wait for a very long time until this happens (essentially because Brownian motion may have very long excursion down to $-\infty$)