# find a function $h:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $h(X(\omega ))=1_A(\omega )$.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ a random variable. Let $A$ being $\sigma (X)-$measurable. I'm having a problem to find a function $h:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $$h(X(\omega ))=1_A(\omega ).$$

In somehow, I would like to set $$h(x)=1_{X(A)}(x),$$
but the problem it's that it can happen that $X^{-1}(X(A))\supsetneq A$, and thus, we can have $X(\omega )\in X(A)$ but $\omega \notin A$. So, is there a way to define $h$ properly or not really ?

Comment: There exists a set $B\subset\mathbb R$ measurable such that $X^{-1}(B)=A$. So set $h(x)=1_B(x)$.

Comment: This result is called factorization lemma (or Doob-Dynkin lemma), see e.g. here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma

Comment: @saz: Thanks, I didn't know this lemma. Sorry to ask you that, but I saw that you are an expert in brownian motion, stochastic calculus... I had a lot of unanswerered question in this area. Would you kindly check them (in case it can be interesting) ? For example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646140/brownian-motion-first-time-it-reach-1-is-in-mean-infinite-does-it-make-sens) ? And others, see my activities in my profile if you have time. Thanks a lot for everything. :)